# Cordova - Build a crosswalk and non-crosswalk version

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

Is it possible to have the cordova build process produce both the Crosswalk APKs as well as the non-Crosswalk APKs for an Android app?

Background: I've got an enterprise Cordova app which is currently migrated to using Crosswalk. To mitigate any risk for an interim period, I'd like to build both the crosswalk APKs as well as a non Crosswalk APK from the same Cordova project. It is distributed through 'Enterprise' channels.

Thanks
Thomas